# What is difference between reg in Verilog code and reg while writing testbench code?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In Verilog code we define our input & output as

```
input x;
output y;
reg y;
```

But while writing the testbench for same we write it as

```
reg x;
wire y;
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference.

A `reg` is a signal that can be assigned to in a procedural block (i.e. an `always` or `initial` block).

A `wire` is a signal that can be assigned to in a continuous assignment (i.e. an `assign` statement), or by connecting it to an output port of a sub-module.

There is no other real distinction.

If a signal is an input to a module (whether in synthesizable code or in a testbench) then it won't be assigned to within that module, so we don't specify that is `reg` or `wire`.

If a signal is an output of a module, we still need to decide whether it is a `reg` or `wire` depending on whether we assign to in a procedural block, a continuous assignment (i.e. an `assign` statement), or as a sub-module output. By default it will be a `wire`, but we can also declare it as `output reg z;` if we need it to be a `reg`.